# Which timer do use?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

In JMeter, we have multiple timers - for instance Uniform Standard Timer, Gaussian Random timer etc.

While researching my query - I found various books and blog which tell me

1. How to add the timers in JMeter
2. What is the internal formula/logic between the timers.

I am somehow confused, which one to use? and when?
For instance, if I am trying to wait for the user to log in, which timer is more appropriate? Uniform? or Gaussian?

Answer (score 1):

As per [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers)

> **Uniform Random Timer**
>
> The Uniform Random Timer pauses the thread by a factor of:
>
> - The next pseudorandom uniformly-distributed value in range between 0.0 (inclusive) and 1.0 (exclusive)
> - Multiplied by “Random Delay Maximum”
> - Plus “Constant Delay Offset”
>
> **Gaussian Random Timer**
> A Gaussian Random Timer calculates the thread delay time using an approach like a Uniform Random Timer does, but instead of a uniformly-distributed pseudorandom value in 0.0 - 0.9 range, the normal (a.k.a. Gaussian) distribution is being used as the first argument for the formula.
>
> There are several algorithms for generating normally distributed values, in JMeter Marsaglia polar method is used which takes the next 2 random values U and V in -1 to 1 range until the S = U2 + V2 > 1 condition is met. Once S is defined it is used in the formula
>
> [image]
>
> to return the next pseudorandom Gaussian (“normally”) distributed value. The first time the method is called it returns X, the second time it will return Y, the third time it starts over and will return the new X, etc.

With regards to "which timer to use and when" - there is no "good" answer which fits all the cases, the timers you've mentioned are used to simulate [think time](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-testing-with-a-think-time) as real users don't hammer the application non-stop, they need some time to "think" between operations. So the decision is up to you:

- on one hand real users perform different delays between operations so it would be good to randomize this delay a little bit if you want the test to be as much realistic as possible
- on the other hand load test needs to be repeatable so it makes sense to go for [Constant Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) to avoid any random factor impacting the test results
- maybe a good idea would be using Uniform or Gaussian random timer initially in order to mimic real users and then for [regression testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing) purposes switch to the Constant Timer for results repeatability purposes